# Must I generate SSH key for each my computer, or to copy the `~/.ssh` directory's content is enough?

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-bash

I use [Git for Windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io/). I have done all steps of [this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) instruction. It works fine. Must I generate the SSH key for each my computer, or to copy the `~/.ssh` directory's content is enough (from my office computer to my home notebook)? Can I use the same SSH key for both computers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generate a separate key for each computer.

This way, if one of the computers gets stolen, you can revoke its key without affecting anything else.

In general, private keys should never be transmitted anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

SLaks is kind of right, but technically spoken, there is no reason for having different SSH keys.

The benefit of having only one key is that you don't have to authorize more than once. If one computer is stolen, you just revoke the regarding key from all places (which you have to do, either case) and then make one new key that you deploy to all of your computers.

I think it's personal preference, which option you choose. But if you have the same key, I think you need to set the same Git config also, regarding username and email (but not sure about it).

IMHO, I am one person (= one identity) so I use one key - which I always found convenient. Git commits use you as a person for identity, not machines. (VPN keys, f.ex., are a different story!)